# Inserting result into database?

Tags: php, mysql, json

I am having this JSON below (for example):

```
[
    {
        "model_id": "437",
        "model_make_id": "alfa-romeo",
        "model_name": "147",
        "model_trim": "1.6 Progression",
        "model_year": "2008",
        "model_body": null,
        "model_engine_position": "Front",
        "model_engine_cc": "1597",
        "model_engine_cyl": "4",
        "model_engine_type": "in-line",
        "model_engine_valves_per_cyl": "4",
        "model_engine_power_ps": "120",
        "model_engine_power_rpm": "4200",
        "model_engine_torque_nm": "146",
        "model_engine_torque_rpm": "4200",
        "model_engine_bore_mm": "82.0",
        "model_engine_stroke_mm": "75.7",
        "model_engine_compression": "10.3:1",
        "model_engine_fuel": "Gasoline",
        "model_top_speed_kph": "195",
        "model_0_to_100_kph": "10.6",
        "model_drive": "Front",
        "model_transmission_type": "Manual",
        "model_seats": "5",
        "model_doors": "3",
        "model_weight_kg": "1265",
        "model_length_mm": "4230",
        "model_width_mm": null,
        "model_height_mm": "1450",
        "model_wheelbase_mm": "2550",
        "model_lkm_hwy": null,
        "model_lkm_mixed": "8.2",
        "model_lkm_city": null,
        "model_fuel_cap_l": "60",
        "model_sold_in_us": "0",
        "model_co2": null,
        "model_make_display": null,
        "make_display": "Alfa Romeo",
        "make_country": "Italy"
    }
]
```

and so on.

My question is how can I input these data into MySQL using PHP probably, having in mind that e.g. `model_id`, `model_make_id` and so on are field names?

Comment: 1) decode json to php structure 2) loop on structure 3) while in loop, insert into mysql 4) ??? 5) profit.

Comment: Start here: http://us3.php.net/json_decode
and here: http://us1.php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php

Comment: Can you reduce your sample code to a more basic structure? All of that is not needed. Also can you include what you've tried?

Comment: @Shawn How much more basic could it be?